# IEnumerable with Add method

Tags: c#, .net

I've seen a simple class that implements a IEnumerable interface.

Then, that class has an Add public method and finally you can instantiate an object by adding items, but what does it mean?

```
public class MyClass : IEnumerable<string> 
{
   public void Add(string s){..} 
}

public class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
       MyClass obj = new { "1", "2" }; // How it works?
   }
}
```

How It works the add method?

Comment: What do you mean by "how it works"? Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers) help?